# How to check if a section is code or data(.elf)?

Tags: shell, gcc, gnu, elf

I am writing a script that supposed to analyze .elf's memory.
More specifically: code size and data size.
The GNU size utility lists the section sizes.

```
>mips-mti-elf-size.exe -A -x -t file.elf
section                              size                 addr                                 
.sec(1)
.sec(2)
.
.sec(i)
.sec(n)
Total                                0x-----
```

I also can check total .text size or total .data size.
Is there a way to decide for each sec(i) whether it is a code or a data?

Comment: I can see only one `.text` section in your example output. Doesn't my answer work for you? If not, please clarify, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm unable to understand what exactly you want if it's **not** printing just the  lines starting with `.text`, `.data` and `.bss`, as your question suggests. If you want something different, please edit your question, show the exact output and make it explicit which lines/parts of it you're interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mips-mti-elf-readelf.exe:

```
 mips-mti-elf-readelf.exe -S file.elf
```

This will return:

```
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .secName                          9014d000 00d000 000480 00  AX  0   0 4096
  ...
```

use Flg: if X is up it is code.